# RxJS Observable - subscribe once every time a condition met

Tags: rxjs, observable

Observables are new to me, so I'm not even sure it's possible (but I would guess it is). What I would like to achieve is having an observable (Angular 2 `http.get` call), and subscribe to it *once* whenever a variable is changed. An example flow would be something like this:

```
let x = false;
// ... somewhere later I change "x" to true
subscribe gets called once, x => false
// stuffs happening, 10 minutes later x => true again
subscribe gets called once, x => false
```

The bigger concept is that I would have a `UserService` and in the constructor I would subscribe to `/api/user/me` once, whenever there is a token change in the localStorage. Is this a valid use case, and if so, how can I do it with observables?

Comment: So what you want to do is to make an api call (once) every time a local storage changes? Just trying to get what you want do do so I can give  decent answer..

Comment: Yup, basically that's it. making an api call (once) every time a local storage item changes and it's not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```js
// Observable that on subscription will result in an api call. It would 
// naturaly have another type in an acaual use case.
let apiCallObservable : Rx.Observable< { someResult: any }>;

let localStorageChangedObservable = new Rx.Subject<boolean>()

localStorageChangedObservable
    // only care about local storage change if not null
    // This is just an example the type of localStorageChangedObservable
    // could be anything you want, and you could check anything you want in the 
    // "where" 
    .where(v => v != null)
    .selectMany(() =>
        // Take one is to make sure we terminate apiCallObservable after recieving
        // one result from it. 
        apiCallObservable.take(1))
    .subscribe(
        (result: { someResult: any}) => {

            // here we would have the result from the call to apiCallObservable
        });

// To execute the chain abouve we would pass values to the localStorageChangedObservable 
// subject like this:

localStorageChangedObservable.onNext(true); // results in api call and result in subscribe
localStorageChangedObservable.onNext(null); // results in nothing.
localStorageChangedObservable.onNext(false); // results in api call and result in subscribe
```

So basically pass something to `localStorageChangedObservable.onNext(...)` when you want to trigger an api call.

Comment: There's a problem, saying `Property 'where' does not exist on type 'Subject<any>'.` I guess it's `filter`?

Comment: Ok, I think this is a problem related to angular 2. You need to include more of rxjs than angular does by default (I am not an angular guru). Here is the rxjs repo https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS, to include everything use the rx.all.js in the dist folder. And I also realisedIi wrote my anser in typescript rather than javascript but i guess you got it anyway?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using typescript so it's cool, thanks! I've replaced `where` with `filter` and `selectMany` with `flatMap` and it looks like it's working, however, for every change it makes 3 requests, but I'm pretty sure that's related to angular! Thanks again!

Comment: The code above should result in one request so it must be related to something else. Make sure you are not subscribing to the api call observable somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, it was a DI mistake in my Angular app.

Comment: If you are using Angular2 the RxJS repo is actually [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs)